# How to use BufferedReader to get data as formated in log file

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am getting data from log file and printing it but it was not as formated as in log file my code is,

```
try

    {
    String strpath="/var/new.log";
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(strpath);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    String ch;
    do {
      ch = br.readLine();

      if (ch != null)
        out.println( ch+"\n");
    } while (ch != null);
    fr.close();
    }

        catch(IOException e){

        out.print(e.getMessage());

        }
```

Data in my file is this format,

```
[1324649399] Nagios 3.3.1 starting... (PID=3751)
[1324649399] Local time is Fri Dec 23 09:09:59 EST 2011
[1324649399] LOG VERSION: 2.0
[1324649400] ndomod: NDOMOD 1.4b9 (10-27-2009) Copyright (c) 2009 Nagios Core Development Team and Community Contributors
[1324649400] ndomod: Could not open data sink!  I'll keep trying, but some output may get lost...
[1324649400] Event broker module '/usr/local/nagios/bin/ndomod.o' initialized successfully.
```

My code is printing it in this Format,

> [1324649399] Nagios 3.3.1 starting... (PID=3751) [1324649399] Local
>   time is Fri Dec 23 09:09:59 EST 2011 [1324649399] LOG VERSION: 2.0
>   [1324649400] ndomod: NDOMOD 1.4b9 (10-27-2009) Copyright (c) 2009
>   Nagios Core Development Team and Community Contributors [1324649400]
>   ndomod: Could not open data sink! I'll keep trying, but some output
>   may get lost... [1324649400] Event broker module
>   '/usr/local/nagios/bin/ndomod.o' initialized successfully.

How can I get it as it is in the log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I may suggest, this is a better way for structuring the loop that outputs the log:

```
String strpath = "/var/new.log", ch;
FileReader fr = null;
try {
    fr = new FileReader(strpath);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    while ((ch = br.readLine()) != null)
        out.println(ch);
} catch (IOException e) {
    out.print(e.getMessage());
} finally {
    if (fr != null)
        fr.close();
}
```

For solving the formatting problems, do as the other answers suggest, and output the log inside a `<pre></pre>` tag

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use HTML properly, to render data in properly formatted output

Comment: i was thinging that i will have to use spliter for this purpose or to get data in array and then print it not willing to to it at html ??? what do you say

Comment: **No** , Just do the java code stuff on service and have a `List` of Strings (lines to be printed on page) and just use HTML table or may be a DIV with proper formatting

Answer (score 0):

Want to preserve the spaces and line breaks use `<pre>` tag. You may also use JSTL `<c:import>` to read the content of file.

```
<c:import url="/var/new.log" var="data"/>
<pre>
 ${data}
</pre>
```